# How match the 2nd 5th 8th 11th etc using Remainder/modulo

Tags: javascript, bash, modulo

I know how to do this with CSS, so in my mind the logic should be the same. However I cannot work out the logic using `remainder` in js

Here is how I need to split things:

```
1 file 'input.mp4' | 1 % 3 = 1
2 inpoint 1 | ?
3 outpoint 2 | 3 % 3 = 0
4 file 'input.mp4' | 4 % 3 = 1
5 inpoint 3 | ?
6 outpoint 4 | 6 % 3 = 0 
7 file 'input.mp4' | 7 % 3 = 1
8 inpoint 5 | ?
9 outpoint 6 | 9 % 3 = 0
```

So the issue I am having is, how can I target the 2,5,8. I cannot divide it by 2 as that will clash with any whole numbers. 4,6,8,10 etc

Comment: Possibly: `n % 1.5`

Comment: simply `(n-2)%3` (or `(n+1)%3`)

Comment: I am not sure why you need to use `remainder`. If you just want to generate 2,5,8 etc. will `2 + n * 3` not work for you? OR I have misunderstood your question?

Comment: This is the condition: `i % 3 == 2`

Comment: Man... I really need to do more lateral thinking to work out my whole numbers :( Thank you guys